# Let X be a topological space let Y be a subset of X and let A be a subset of Y. Of A is closed in Y and Y is closed in X, show that A is closed in X

Tags: general-topology

Can someone help me prove this:
Let X be a topological space let Y be a subset of X and let A be a subset of Y. If A is closed in Y and Y is closed in X, show that A is closed in X.

Use Theorem 3.4 - Let X be a topological space, and let $Y \subset X$ have the subspace topology. Then $C \subset Y$ is closed in Y if and only if C = D $\cap$ Y for some closed set D in X.

Definition of the subspace topology - Let X be a topological space and let Y be a subset of X. Define $T_y$ = {U $\cap$ Y | U is open in X}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is closed in $Y$. Then we can write $A$ as $D \cap Y$ for some closed set $D \subseteq X$. Since both $D$ and $Y$ are closed in $X$, and since the intersection of any family of closed sets is closed, $A$ is closed as a subset of $X$.